# Flutter GridView to take all screen space?

Tags: flutter

Is there anyway (except using MediaQuery context to get device screen size), to let GridView outspread the whole screen?

This is my simple app right now:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './bottom-navigation.dart';

void main() => runApp(_MyApp());

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: WBottomNavigation(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`WBottomNavigation` is thee botton navigation bar

This is the result of the code:
[image]

But the result I want is (where red rectangles are images):
[image]

Comment: are you bound to use only ``GridView`` if not you could use other widgets to achieve your target easily?

Comment: @OMiShah I'm not bound to this restriction, But I do need 2x2 widgets (so obviously using gridView is the first thing I did). I just don't know if using `MediaQuery context` is bad or good practice. Because using the last, could simply solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reading your comments, you are not bound to use only `GridView`, than an easy solution would be to use `Column` and `Row`. `Column` and `Row` outspread the whole available space. In this case, you attach column - it outspread the available space only.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './widgets/bottom-navigation.dart';

void main() => runApp(_MyApp());

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: WBottomNavigation(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange, this is a solution but it seems now we did this we need if and else for different resolutions. If we want to make 2 column to 3 or 4, it's going to require code change. I think questioner it self is not having this idea.

Comment: Yes @ParthDave I totally agree with you, I think questioner is not sure, that what he/she want to achieve and with how or what approach.

Comment: @ParthDave  Maybe he knows that it will always consists of 2 cols and 2 rows. 2X2 Always for his case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property in Every `Listview` and `GridView` named `Aspect Ratio`
Try to play with it with some numbers

More about it is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html)

*Seems 0.5 just works fine*, (Maybe you would need Mediaquery later on to fit the images later according to the device using aspect ratio.)

```
      childAspectRatio: 0.5,
```

*Whole Code will be*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 0.5,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would `0.5` work fine? It does not. All it does - applying 2xWidth  to each gridView item's height.

Comment: "There is a property in Every Listview and GridView named Aspect Ratio Try to play with it with some numbers" I clearly said try to play with this property, which means by changing the value, which suits your layout better.

Comment: I really think it is bad practice to just drop some numbers and hope for it to succeed somehow. It is not even responsive.

Comment: I never said its a answer, infect I thought you needed a workaround for a while, So, I found a approach which seems working, for me and 3 others lol

Comment: So basically I cant really do it with GridView? Because all the answers are kind of "TO GUESS" solution. Is there a way to do so without GridView?

Comment: Check my answer, it's not guessing work, it's proper code and don't need to think about the calculations yourself.

Comment: Shalvi, Please check @ParthDave  answer.It's working properly, without any number guessing game.

Comment: I'm not sure about this question now, if he is using GridView means he has more items but he needed to fir the item. The question should be how to make 2x2 grid and not to take all space. Because the answer which was accepted is misleading with question.

Answer (score 1):

childAspectRatio is the correct variable we need to set for this aspect Ratio means what one child's width height ratio will be i.e (width/ height) so we want 2 columns and 2 rows and here we have width and we will split for columnCounts then same goes for height, we will split the height with the minimumCount we need to show
Here's the code:

[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/parthdave93/fc4d6c2fa53a7d8b902232f95cc24d61.js)

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MaterialColor actualColor = Colors.red;
  var appbarPresent = false;
  var bottomBarPresent = false;
  var columnCount = 2;
  var minRowCountOnScreen = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("_MyHomePageState build");
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var width = size.width;
    var height = size.height;
    if(appbarPresent){
      height -= kToolbarHeight;
    }
    if(bottomBarPresent){
      height -= kBottomNavigationBarHeight;
    }
    //childAspectRatio is the correct variable we need to set for this
    //aspect Ratio means what one child's width height ratio will be i.e (width/ height)
    //so we want 2 columns and 2 rows and here we have width and we will split for columnCounts
    //then same goes for height, we will split the height with the minimumCount we need to show
    var aspectRatio = (width / columnCount) / (height / minRowCountOnScreen) ;
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: columnCount,
        childAspectRatio: aspectRatio,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(
            'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Image.network(
            'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Image.network(
            'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Image.network(
            'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

set `minRowCountOnScreen`, `columnCount`, `appbarPresent` and `bottomBarPresent` as per your requirements also if we need padding do remove padding margins from width and height to stabilise the aspect ratio. no need to change the aspect ratio after this.
[image: Result]

Comment: The question was asked for GridView items to be 2x2 and not for how to design, This answer is based on the GridView childAspect ratio dynamic calculations to not to calculate and handle everything. I suggested edits for the question to match with the answer selected. Ignore this answer if it does not match after new revision.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the `childAspectRatio`   to `1.8 / 2.3`, it'll also work fine

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import './bottom-navigation.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(_MyApp());
    
    class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 1.8 / 2.3,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Image.network(
                  'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: WBottomNavigation(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```